# Как сделать список в ScrollView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-scrollview

Есть `ScrollView`, в нем будут два списка `RecyclerView`. Как это реализовать, чтобы была иллюзия общей целостности содержимого? Я так понял нужно чтобы списки были высотой по содержимому и скролл перехватыл `ScrollView`.   Или нет?

Comment: Проще, кажется,в этом случае один ресайклер использовать и всё

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, так будет еще куча `View` помимо списков)

Comment: Помещайте их все в отдельные ViewHolder. Это гораздо проще и правильнее, чем городить конструкцию из ScrollView и нескольких костыльных RecyclerView